# Can you take the limit as $x \to \infty$ of an expression such as $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, soft-question, summation

Consider the function

$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$

I'm not really concerned with its convergence properties, what I am concerned with is if it is possible to take the limit as $x \to \infty$ of a function like this where we have a summation over an infinite set of numbers that become infinitely large?

If you take $x \to \infty$ it seems like there will be a problem as you will be subtracting an infinite number from an infinite number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take limits of functions that map values in a topological space to values in a topological space.  Thus, before you take a limit, you need to know what the function maps to what.  If a function maps a real number $x$ to an expression like $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ which has no conventional meaning as a number, then you have to  give it such a meaning, or a meaning as a member of some other topological space, before you can speak of limits of the function.

$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ lacks conventional meaning because it's divergent, but there are conventions which give meaning to some divergent series. There are actually books with "divergent series" in the title.  Note that $ \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ occurs for the one value of $n$ which is closest to $x$, and that $\ln(|x - n|)$ is negative only for a couple of values of $n$, so for $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$, the sum $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ can be seen most conventionally as $+\infty$. The limit might, if you decide to give a meaning $+\infty$ to the sum when $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, most naturally be seen as being itself $+\infty$.  There are contexts, like Baby Rudin ch. 3, in which limits of real numbers are discussed as including $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

The problem which you mention, of subtracting an infinite number from another infinite number, only occurs when $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Yes, it is a problem in trying to give $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ a meaning.

Comment: Well $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It seems to me like we can't even get as far as saying its divergent because it cant be evaluated...ie. we can't evaluate all the terms and therefore we can't evaluate the expression itself? $\dots + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x - (-1)|) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x|) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x - 1|) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x - 2|) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x - 3|) + \dots$ doesn't seem to make sense as we can't evaluate all the terms?!

Comment: $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \ln(|x - n|)$ for $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$ is a divergent series almost all of whose terms are positive, as noted in the answer.  If you now consider another expression, $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(|x - n|)$, that is somewhat different puzzle.  However, each term of the latter sum is $+\infty$ so I guess, under some conventions, you can say that the latter infinite sum is $+\infty$.